# Laravel sanctum throws unauthenticated in Postman

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum, postman-pre-request-script

building SPA application and testing endpoints with Postman. Heads up that my routes are declared in api.php. I'm able to hit CSRF endpoint(/sanctum/csrf-cookie) and receive the cookie, session. However, when I'm trying to reach the protected(auth:sanctum) route, I receive unauthenticated message. Postman hierarchy looks like this. Forgot to mention that the pre-request script is inside the collection:

```
App(Collection) -> 
 Auth(Folder) -> 
  Requests -> 
   (Get) CSRF,
   (Post) Login,
   (Post) Register.
```

Under the App collection I have Pre-request script, which looks like this(see below). I'm able to console.log the cookie variable, which shows the exact value of XSRF-TOKEN:

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

jar.get("http://localhost:3000", "XSRF-TOKEN", (error, cookie) => {
    pm.request.addHeader({
        key: "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        value: cookie
    });

    pm.request.addHeader({
        key: "Referer",
        value: "http://localhost:3000"
    });
});
```

In my .env file my session configuration looks like this:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
```

sanctum.php looks like this, where APP_URL is localhost:5000, and the FRONTEND_URL is localhost:3000:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

Any thoughts what can cause the issue?

Comment: Have you checked your Kernel.php?

Make sure you uncomment \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class

Comment: Yes. This class is added to api array list.